# What is the difference between Platform-Independent and Cross-Platform?

Tags: cross-platform, libraries, virtual-machine, platform-independent

I have seen a lot of C/C++ Libraries and Gui Toolkits. Among them there are some like GTK+  , Qt , Swing etc. which claim to be platform-*independent*. While some , like WxWidgets, SWT etc. which claim to be *cross*-platform. At first I thought it to be just a change in wording, but the terms have been used with such consistency that I have started to wonder. What *is* the difference?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the source language of the library.

Comment: That's abusing the tag system. Tags are about the content of the question, not who you want to look at it.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I believe that when something claims its platform-independent it usually uses some kind of virtual machine or other tricks so it can work above the hardware and os level. Specific installers of the vm for different platforms but the same vm for all of them. Cross-platform means that the library works as is for a number of different platforms. Out of the box. Chances are I'm mistaken or what I said needs a ton of clarifications but I think the core idea is correct...

Comment: @burningprodigy: I guess there aren't many people here interested in the minutae of platform terminology. And no, you can't. There is no C++ content in the question, C++ is not at all relevant to the question.

Comment: You mention Swing and Qt in the same sentence. C++ is not relevant here as it also applies to Java.

Comment: @burning: You're not getting many views because you don't have a real problem to solve.

Comment: @DeadMG Sorry for rolling back your changes. And for putting irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cross-platform only implies that you support multiple platforms. It usually means Linux, Mac, and Windows. Platform-independent implies that you support any platform that your language supports- i.e., you depend on no behaviour that is not specified in the language specification. However that's just my personal opinion and most uses just take both of them to mean "multiple platforms", usually "Windows and ...".

Answer (score 6):

For what its worth, this is what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform) has to say on the matter:

> In order for software to be considered **cross-platform**, it must be able to function on more than one computer architecture or operating system.
>
> Software that is **platform independent** does not rely on any special features of any single platform, or, if it does, handles those special features such that it can deal with multiple platforms

Answer (score 3):

"Platform-independent" would usually be a program written in a high-level language that doesn't need recompiling or adjusting for another platform and can just run "as is" (Java, most Perl scripts, etc.) as long as the particular platform implements the language runtime. This is possible when there are layers below the program that deal with different platforms (the VM or the interpreter).

"Cross-platform" implies that the program can be compiled/adjusted for multiple platforms, but not for *any* platform. Think of `#ifdef`'s in C and C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform means your program can work on different platforms example Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Platform Independent means your code is **Write once Run Anywhere** i.e. you don't need to change your code to run on different platforms

*All platform independent programs are cross-platform but vice versa not true*